# Split pane solution explorer in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any setting or plug-in to improve the solution explorer? Specifically, it would be amazing if I could have something like the windows file explorer, with folders on the left and files on the right (or split in two panes I can arrange any way I like).

In larger projects, I feel like I am constantly frustrated by scrolling up and down trying to find things, it's driving me crazy! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for VS 2010

Mindscape Visual Studio File Explorer

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7193af78-b06e-48dd-8994-9deb2bfa1959

Also check Productivity Power Tools (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home). There is nice thing - Solution Navigator

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this add in](http://vsflatsolutionexp.codeplex.com/) seems to be for visual studio 2005 but the source code is there

Comment: That looks interesting, I will check it out. It would certainly help but I'd still love a split pane solution... does anyone actually use visual studio with really big projects? :)